# How to config IIS to redirect to custom error page when accessing unsupported extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, custom-error-pages

I've tried some ways to deploy my custom error page (e.g. error.aspx) onto my website:

- Added customErrors: `<customErrors mode="On"
  defaultRedirect="error.aspx" />`
- Added httpError:  `<httpErrors>
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" /> <error
  statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="error.aspx"
  responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> </httpErrors>`

Currently, I can point this URL to my custom error page:

http://test.localdev.net/random_text.aspx

However, I failed for those kind of URL (unsupported extension), for these URLs IIS will use its own 404 page:

http://test.localdev.net/Default.random

Could anyone help me to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

are you using iis7 or later in integrated mode?  Otherwise I think you need to configure error pages in iis itself.

Comment: Yes, IIS 7, Application Pool is in Integrated mode.

Comment: try adding existingResponse="Replace" to webServer/httpErrors